# React Native IOS release build js tree shaking

Tags: ios, react-native, tree-shaking

I have following js code in my react native project

```
import ...;

const {PLATFORM} = Config;
if(PLATFORM === 'APN'){

   async function onAppleLogin(callback = ()=>{}){
       // some logic here
   }
}

class LoginPage extends React.Component{

   onAppleBtnPres = () => {
       console.log(typeof onAppleLogin); // <-------- issue on here

       if(typeof onAppleLogin !== function){
          // some logic here
          return false
       }

       onAppleLogin(()=>{
          // some logic here
       })
   }

   render(){
      return (
         <Button 
             onPress={this.onAppleBtnPres} 
             title = "Apple Sign In"
         />
   }
}
```

In debugger, "typeof onAppleLogin" produce difference value in ios release/debug configurations.

**Conditions below had been examinated**

1. typeof onAppleLogin -> undefined // release configurations
2. typeof onAppleLogin -> [function] // debug configurations

My RN ios run properly with debug configuration, but issue comes up when using release configuration *(onAppleLogin function always undefined)*.

I'm using RN version 0.64 and I leave all ios configuration settings default except signing and capabilities.

Comment: Metro bundler of react-native which is used to bundle your js code does not support tree shaking. Therefore that is not the error. The more, you question is nearly impossible to understand.

Comment: @AdamRi Sorry to my poor declaration. I had edit my writing and hope that clearly enough to declare my question. 
In simplicity, my RN IOS behave difference in debug and release configuration, a function called "onAppleLogin" is undefined when run with release configurations but exist in debug configurations. 
I tried to find out the reason why that function (onAppleLogin) "was being remove" when i building with release schema.